# C++ operator* overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the following Matrix class that seems to be working well so far

```
template<typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
class Matrix
{
    public:
        Matrix(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> m)
        {
            // snip
        }

        T& operator()(const std::size_t i, const std::size_t j)
        {
            return m_data.at(i + j * N);
        }

        const T& operator()(const std::size_t i, const std::size_t j) const
        {
            return m_data.at(i + j * N);
        }

        Matrix<T,M,N> operator*(const T n)
        {
            // snip
        }

    private:
        std::array<T, M * N> m_data;
};
```

However the overloaded operator* only allows scalar multiplication if the scalar is on the right hand side of the operator.  I would like to allow this operation even if the scalar is on the left hand side of the operator, so I tried adding this to the `Matrix.hpp` file:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
Matrix<T,M,N> operator*(const T lhs, const Matrix<T,M,N> &rhs)
{
    return rhs * lhs;
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
In file included from test.cpp:1:0:
Matrix.hpp: In instantiation of ‘Matrix<T, M, N> operator*(T, const Matrix<T, M, N>&) [with T = double; long unsigned int M = 3ul; long unsigned int N = 3ul]’:
test.cpp:21:13:   required from here
Matrix.hpp:137:13: error: passing ‘const Matrix<double, 3ul, 3ul>’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘Matrix<T, M, N> Matrix<T, M, N>::operator*(T) [with T = double; long unsigned int M = 3ul; long unsigned int N = 3ul]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  return rhs * lhs;
```

If I remove `const` from the Matrix `rhs` parameter the code compiles and works correctly.  I would like to understand why the code does not compile with the `const` in place?

Comment: Because your member `operator *` isn't `const`. It should be.

Comment: Also, I advise you create `operator *=` first, and then write `operator*` in terms of `*=`  In other words, the code you "snipped" from your `operator *` function should be moved to `*=`, then `operator*` becomes a 3 line function.

Comment: Have a member operator *= and two freestanding operators Matrix * T and T * Matrix

Comment: I wonder about the use of `at()` in your code.  Do you really want to require clients to create a try/catch block, and to be able to somehow recover from the error?  (It's also not really good for bounds checking in this case, since you need to verify both indices separately.  But that should probably be an `assert`; you don't want to throw an exception in the case of a program error.)

Comment: And you probably don't want to pass `Matrix` by value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `operator*` free functions.  (You'll need two of
them, one with the scalar on the right, and one with it on the left.)
You probably also want an `operator*=`; it may be convenient to use this
operator to implement the two `operator*`.

Answer (score -1):

When you write operator as the member method then the first argument is always "this" instance of the class. If you want to write `scalar * matrix` then you must write the operator as non-member function. It is usually done as friend method.

```
template<typename T>
Matrix<T> operator*(T const& n, Matrix<T> m)
{
    // snip
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T> operator*(Matrix<T> m, T const& n)
{
    return n * m;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't make it a friend unless I were making it inline, in the class itself.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well, it is not necessary to make them friend when there are access methods to members. Nevertheless it is quite common pattern to use friends when class _have_ a non-member operator. I think it is a matter of style and convention on particular project.

Comment: I would appreciate if anybody giving -1 write a short comment why it is not useful. Actually when there are 2 similar responses to the question then the problem might be in the question itself. Finally I have found a compiler which has the same error message as yours. So I realized that your `operator*()` is actually written as non-member function although it is not obvious from the code. The problem of your code is that `operator*(scalar, const matrix)` takes constant matrix but the call `matrix::operator(scalar)` is not const. So just add the const to the `member operator*()`.

Comment: `operator*` is _usually_ implemented in terms of `operator*=`, and doesn't need to access anything but the copy constructor and this operator.  Which both should be public.